# Laravel image validation bypassed by hackers

Tags: php, laravel, shell, security

I'm using Laravel framework 3 in all my projects and all goes perfectly.

Always I use Laravel default form validation, especially the image rule to prevent people from  uploading bad files except images.

```
"field_name" => "required|image"
```

But yesterday a hacker bypassed the validation and uploaded a ton of shells.

Can anyone help me protect my projects from hacking?

Comment: One way it to add customs validation rules. This issue may have been solved since. You can update your Laravel Framework to make sure that you have security updates but you are using Laravel 3 and that can take some time. Are you sure that the hacker has used the field_name to upload a ton of shells ?

Comment: You might want to check if your server has other http method enabled (like PUT, DELETE) as well.

Comment: How are you even sure that the flaw is in the image validation? Even though your Laravel version is old, I don't think that it is the source of the problem.

Comment: @TivBroc yes im sure .

Comment: @frz3993 yes they are enabled whats wrong with thos methods?

Comment: @JhulianoMoreno im sure its from the image validation dude i found shells in the uploading folder .

Comment: @Hamzar, I don't know how to explain it exactly. But lets say you have a path in your webroot like `/upload/images/`, a PUT request to `/upload/images/script.sh` will save the body of the request to `script.sh` on your server. And DELETE will delete it. Usually, PUT and DELETE will be redirected to a script that will handle it, or disabled if not needed.

Comment: @frz3993 it will save the body request evenif there is no file that handle this operation ?!!!

Comment: @Hamzar even that doesn't prove anything... You would need some sort of log with the hacker requests or find the vulnerabilitie in the code to prove it, otherwise you are just assuming things that might not be true. Anyways, double check how you used the framework for the file upload and if you think the problem is with Laravel just implement your own file upload. Shouldn't take more than 2 hours to do implement a simple secure file upload.

Comment: @Hamzar additionally, a time ago I answered a question regarding secure file upload. If you are interested check:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560949/secure-uploading-file/21564228#21564228